# Why is are my data looking like that and what am I doing wrong?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm conducting an experiment (during 10 days of observation) to compare four different topologys (refered as conditions) of ant nests named NTS, NTC, TS, and TC. I am aware that the death rate in my experiment is very low, but why is there a vertical line at the end of my survplot ? No tutorial on YouTube talk about this issue...

My data set contains 5 columns which are named : ID, Statut, Time, Condition and Colony. ID : the ID using to refer to an individual (not realevant here). Statut : 0 or 1, 0 is for dead and 1 for alive. Time : the day of the death and 10 if still alive at the end of the experiment. Condition : information on condition (NTS, NTC, TS and TC) Colony : from 1 to 6, just the label of the colony.

I dont know to share proprely my data, so here is a google drive link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QKAZof0dQw-K4uqmK2hnnPGzkAAcmXsA/view?usp=sharing

Here is my R script :

```
morta <- read.csv("mortalite.test.csv", head=TRUE, sep = ";")
morta$Statut <- as.integer(morta$Statut)
morta$Condition <- as.factor(morta$Condition)
morta$Time <- as.numeric(morta$Time)
table(morta$Statut)
table(morta$Time)
summary(morta)
head(morta)
complete_cases <- complete.cases(morta)
sum(complete_cases)  # Nombre d'observations complètes
sum(!complete_cases) # Nombre d'observations manquantes

surv_obj <- Surv(morta$Time, morta$Statut)
fit_km <- survfit(surv_obj ~ Condition, data = morta)
print(fit_km)
logrank_testCondition <- survdiff(surv_obj ~ Condition, data = morta)
logrank_testColony <- survdiff(surv_obj ~ Colony, data = morta)
print(logrank_testCondition)
print(logrank_testColony)

ggsurvplot(fit_km, data = morta,
           risk.table = TRUE, 
           pval=TRUE, 
           conf.int = FALSE)+
  labs(x = "Temps (en jour)", y = "Probabilité de survie")
```

And here is an image of :[my survplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drwjy.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your awsners

Something looking like that :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTxRR.png)

data for morta:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:20, Statut = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Time = c(4, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), Condition = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NTC", "NTS", "TC", "TS"), class = "factor"), Colony = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. There's likely something wrong with your data.

Comment: For data `dput(head(morta, n = 20))` and paste `structure(...)` above in your question.

Comment: @Chris here is the output : 
> dput(head(morta, n = 20))
structure(list(ID = 1:20, Statut = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Time = c(4, 
8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10), Condition = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NTC", 
"NTS", "TC", "TS"), class = "factor"), Colony = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Accessed your data, thanks, and reproduce your 'disappointing' plot. As 'Condition=TS' is last plotted among conditions (an assumption I make), and as there is so little death in the data, might the Condition=TS' be overwriting Conditions (NTC, NTS, TC) as they may all reflect the same trajectory, i.e., you plot tells the survival story to this point in data time?

Comment: @Chris, yes,  the experiment was made during 10 days. Is that your question ? And thanks for taking time to help me !